# Handling mouseover for multiple controls in same method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to handle mouseover and mouseleave events for multiple controls in the same method. My form has 10 different buttons which I need to handle their mouse events. Now normally I would do something like this:

```
  public Form1()
  {
       InitializeComponent();
       button1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(button1_MouseEnter);
       button1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(button1_MouseLeave);
  }

  void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img1));
  }


  void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
  }
```

But since that I have 10 controls which are basically handled the same way, I find it impractical to do a seperate method for each control, in my case its 20 methods that will do almost the same thing but to a different control.

So is there a way to integrate those events into one and just determine which control should be handled.

Edit:

Can thee be a way to determine which exact control raised the event, lets assume that I have a picturebox which changes the image depending on the button being hovered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use the same event handler for all controls when you assign the handlers. Inside the handler, use an `if()` to determine which control raised the event.

```
void SomeEvent_Handler ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if ( sender == btn1 ) // event is from btn1
    {
        btn1....;
    }
    else if ( sender == checkbox1 ) // event is from checkbox1
    {
        checkbox1.....;
    }
}
```

Comment: So how do I determine which control is the sender. Please bear in mind that I am completely new to c#

Comment: If you're going to have a separate if block for each *control*, you're better off with separate handlers...  How does this help?

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, you're right, although it's possible to merge some of the logic using names or the Tag property. It's a programming style one chooses. I usually just bite the bullet and use separate handlers but I can see the advantage of just having a single function that handles all similar controls. This is useful when most controls use the same code but some have something slightly different.

Comment: @xxbbcc I'd refactor it to have separate handlers that call a shared method.  It'd actually (most likely) be fewer lines of code that way, and also make more sense, as each method would have one purpose.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, that could work, too. I usually try to keep minimal code and maximum separation but with UI logic, it's sometimes very hard to do that. I'm not trying to say this approach is better than any other - I see it simply as yet another tool. I agree with you on your points but I don't discount this approach either.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the same handler for all of your controls, especially since [BackgroundImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx) is a shared property of `Control`, not `Button`:

```
      public Form1()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
           button1.MouseEnter += control_MouseEnter;
           button1.MouseLeave += control_MouseLeave;
           button2.MouseEnter += control_MouseEnter;
           button2.MouseLeave += control_MouseLeave;
      }

      void control_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           Control control = sender as Control;
           if (control != null)
               control.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img1));
      }


      void control_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           Control control = sender as Control;
           if (control != null)
               control.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
      }
```

Comment: So is there a way to determine what that control is exactly. Can I compare it to my existing controls. Lets say I have to show an image in a picture box and that image changes depending on which control being hovered?

Comment: @RedSerpent yes, it's possible, look at my answer, I added a bit more detail to the `if`.

Comment: @RedSerpent If you want to check for specific controls, I'd have separate event handlers (and maybe a shared method they all use).  If you want to check for types of controls, you could use `Button button = sender as Button;`, and then handle all "Button" instances the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, just subscribe the same method to all your events and sender will give you button, which caused event.